# C++ `using {var}` is not a member of {child class} - when using `std::deque` in MSVC or Clang

Tags: c++, templates

The code below gives the error `error C2039: 'value_type': is not a member of 'Child_Container'` on line 7. This happens in MSVC and Clang, but not with GCC. Thereby when using `std::deque`, but not `std::set`, `std::vector`. Does anyone know why? Thank you!

```
#include <deque>

template<typename T_Container>
struct _View
{
    using           NOPE = typename T_Container::value_type;
};

template<typename T_type, typename T_Self>
struct Base_Container
{
    using value_type = T_type;
    std::deque<_View<T_Self>>   _views;
};

struct Child_Container : public Base_Container<double, Child_Container>
{
    // using value_type = double; // Even with this line.
    using base = Base_Container<value_type, Child_Container>;
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably unrelated, but careful with how you use underscores. An underscore followed by a capital letter is reserved for use by The Implementation. See [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for the tip. It is actually in a namespace.

Comment: @JMRC, Whether it's in a namespace is irrelevant; said names are reserved in any context (i.e., an implementation could name a macro that or use it as a compiler builtin).

Comment: @user4581301 Ahh. Didn't think about that.

Comment: This appears to be library-specific rather than compiler-specific. Clang compiles this with libstdc++, but not with libc++.

Comment: @chris I noticed that as well. There must be some difference in container templates. https://godbolt.org/z/ThzfKEhTh

Comment: Unsurprisingly, using a `self_t` directly instead of indirecting it through CRTP works fine: https://godbolt.org/z/3eaj4756a

Comment: Note the only `std` container class templates you're allowed to instantiate with an incomplete type as the first template argument are `std::vector`, `std::list`, and `std::forward_list`. A library might make it work for other containers, but it's not guaranteed. And there's a relationship between completeness of class types and implicit instantiations of class templates, but I haven't worked out exactly how that applies to this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable here is simply whether `std::deque` requires its element type to be **complete** when it is instantiated.  (Of course it must be complete when certain *member functions* are instantiated, but that’s separate.)  If it does, you end up needing your `value_type` before it’s declared, which produces the error observed.  C++17 requires that `std::vector` support incomplete types, but says nothing about `std::deque`, which is why this varies per standard library.

Comment: The Standard does say one thing about `std::deque`, in the overall general statement that unless stated otherwise, using an incomplete type as a template argument for a template in the standard library results in undefined behavior. (An implementation which makes it work for `std::deque` anyway is a valid result of undefined behavior.)

Comment: Yeah. Ain't UB a stinker?

Comment: I turned the `std::deque` into a pointer and now it works. Thank you!